# During a git rebase, how can I keep the original and discard changes?

Tags: git, rebase

I am doing a rebase and have come to a file with conflicts, but these conflicts are basically impossible to resolve. The best way to deal with the situation would be to tell git to ignore the changes and keep the original. I can then go back and re-edit the file to make the changes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have encountered a merge conflict you can do this

```
git checkout --ours file
```

or the other way round

```
git checkout --theirs file
```

Comment: This will take you back to the conflicted version :
  git checkout --conflict=merge file