# Cannot resolve GitHub conflict in PR

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a PR in a GitHub repository (some one else his PR), which cannot be merged because of conflicts.

What can I do to fix those conflicts by myself?

I tried the following:

1. Create new branch from PR
2. Checkout, pull and merge master
3. Fix the conflicts manually. Lot of work.
4. Test it locally, it works. :)
5. Stage all the files `git add .`
6. Commit and push
7. Create a new PR
8. And then still the message "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved".

What I'm doing wrong? Locally everything works and `git status` reports:

> On branch branch2
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/branchX'.
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

PS: If I redo "merge master", all the conflicts are back. Don't get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual workflow is:

- make sure yo have the latest `master` from `upstream`, `upstream` being the name of the remote referencing the original repo in [a triangular workflow](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows#improved-support-for-triangular-workflows))

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/8943755/5dcdcae4-354a-11e5-9f82-915914fad4f7.png]

```
git fetch upstream
```

Then you create your own branch (in your own fork, where you have fetch the PR branch from another fork)

```
git checkout -b branch2 otherfork/PRbranch
```

And you **rebase that branch on top of `upstream/master`**

This is key: no merge: rebase only, that way, you will resolve conflicts, and the resulting history of `branch2` will be additional commits on top of `upstream/master`, which will make the PR a simple fast-forward merge when applied (merged) to `master` in  the original repo (the `upstream` one).

Comment: Can you explain me why merge isn't working and how I fix my current situation without redoing everything? (current state = merged with master and fixed conflicts, so step 5)

Comment: @Julian you would still need a rebase, but this time, you can resolve any conflict by keeping your version (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8566376/6309) (actually, keeping "theirs", since a rebase switches ours and theirs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)